# How to retrieve compute cluster name from ComputeTarget.list(workspace=ws) in Azure ML

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-sdk-python

I use `clist=`[ComputeTarget.list(workspace=ws)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.computetarget?view=azure-ml-py#list-workspace-) to find a list of compute target in the workspace, which looks like this:

```
[{
   "id": "/subscriptions/94e14ad4-bf97-47e8-aae0-f9b85a7befa8/resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/.../computes/std-ds3-v2",
   "name": "std-ds3-v2",
   "location": "southcentralus",
   "tags": null,
   "properties": {
     "description": null,
     "computeType": "ComputeInstance",
     "computeLocation": "southcentralus",
     "resourceId": null,
     "provisioningErrors": null,
     "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
     "properties": {
       "vmSize": "STANDARD_DS3_V2",
       "applications": [
         {
           "displayName": "Jupyter",
           "endpointUri": "https://std-ds3-v2.southcentralus.instances.azureml.ms"
         },
         {
           "displayName": "Jupyter Lab",
           "endpointUri": "https://std-ds3-v2.southcentralus.instances.azureml.ms/lab"
         },
         {
           "displayName": "RStudio",
           "endpointUri": "https://std-ds3-v2-8787.southcentralus.instances.azureml.ms"
         }
       ],
     ...
     ...
   }
 }]
```

The `clist` object looks like a list of dictionary elements. I want to retrieve the dictionary element `"name": "std-ds3-v2"` dynamically, so I tried `clist[0]['name']` but got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-df855b4d0107> in <module>
----> 1 clist[0]['name']

TypeError: 'ComputeInstance' object is not subscriptable
```

How to retrieve `"name": "std-ds3-v2"` from the `clist` object?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [x.name for x in ComputeTarget.list(workspace=ws)]
['aks-cluster', 'aks-a2-cluster', 'cpu-compute']

>>> list(ws.compute_targets.keys())
['aks-cluster', 'aks-a2-cluster', 'cpu-compute']
```